# How do I 'Cascade delete' after a tables have been created

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

In Sql Server, I have a Company table with 4 FK relationships:

[image: Foreign Key Relationships]

I need to delete certain Companies where a specific column is Null. But I need to delete all of the related records in the other tables.
How can I do this after these tables have been created and designed?'

I have tried this for the Load relationship but I get an error:

```
ALTER TABLE "Company"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_Company"
FOREIGN KEY ("Company")
REFERENCES "Load" ("Company")
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ERROR:
Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Foreign key 'FK_Company' references invalid column 'Company' in referencing table 'Company'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cant delete them without removing the referential integrity from the other tables. I believe

Comment: Is there a Company column in table load?

Comment: may be Company column change into not null

Answer (score 0):

If those constraints were not designed to be `ON DELETE CASCADE`, there is a good chance that that was done for a reason. So unless you know what you are doing, I would advice against changing this.

And, it's not very hard to write the delete queries that simulate the cascade:

```
DELETE FROM child_table WHERE parent_id IN
    (SELECT parent_id FROM parent_table WHERE attr = ?)

DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE attr = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Load table and other tables would need the company table's key defined as a foreign key.  In this example its the Load table's CompanyID column that references the Company table's CompanyID column.  CompanyID is the primary key of the Company table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Load ADD CONSTRAINT
FK_Load_Company FOREIGN KEY
(
CompanyID
) REFERENCES dbo.Company
(
CompanyID
) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
 ON DELETE  CASCADE
```